# __main__ has no attribute preload problem from p5 library in python

Tags: python

every time I run this code I get the error: AttributeError: module '**main**' has no attribute 'preload'

I run this code

```
from p5 import setup, draw, size, background, run
import numpy as np


width = 500
height = 500

def setup():
    size(width, height)


def draw():
    background(51)

run()
```

and get the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Admin/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\p5\sketch\userspace.py", line 160, in run
    preload_method = __main__.preload
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'preload'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convention is to include `if __name__ == '__main__':` when running a python file by itself. the docs follow this convention in [their examples](https://p5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/structure/statements%20and%20comments.html). this script ran without the error but I'm not familiar with p5 and what it's supposed to show

```py
       │ File: test.py
───────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1   │ from p5 import *
   2   │ import numpy as np
   3   │
   4   │
   5   │ width = 500
   6   │ height = 500
   7   │
   8   │ def setup():
   9   │     size(width, height)
  10   │
  11   │
  12   │ def draw():
  13   │     background(51)
  14   │
  15   │ if __name__ == '__main__':
  16   │     run()
```

Comment: OH thank you! its also the importing that was wrong too, thank you for that

Comment: I'm not sure the `import *` is necessary but it's what was done in the examples I saw in the docs. glad it helped!

Comment: I tried it without the ``` import * ``` and it did the same error so I don't know